# LINQPad: LINQ to SQLite DataContext via System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, datacontext, linqpad

I'm fairly new to LINQ and trying to find a more elegant way (other than ADO.Net) to query and manipulate data in a SQLite database. I'm using System.Data.SQLite and wondering if there is a DataContext class or a way to use DataContext class to work with SQLite.

I believe LINQPad uses the same assembly for its SQLite/MySQL driver and with it I can execute C# expressions like so:

```
from c in Collection
where c.Length > 3
select c
```

What can I do to use those same LINQ expressions with my SQLite databases in my applications?

Comment: LINQPad uses Matt Warren's IQueryable toolkit for querying SQLite and MySQL. This is one of the few LINQ-to-XXX engines that can reliably translate a wide range of non-trivial LINQ queries into SQL.

Comment: By the way, thank you so much for LINQPad. It does so much for my development. It's one of my all time favorite development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Data.SQLite supports the ADO.NET Entity Framework, so you should be able to just add an Entity Framework mapping and point it to your SQLite connection.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/sqlite.wmv